# What is this "studentrecord"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I based my code on Duncan Betts' codes for my assignment but I don't understand it and it seems like it has been 3 years since he last logged on so I can't ask him.

Can you please explain where did the "studentrecord" code come from? What is it?

```
num = int(input("How many students?: "))

physics_students = [[input("Input student name: "),float(input("Input grade: "))] for studentrecord in range(num)]
physics_students.sort(key=lambda studentrecord: float(studentrecord[1]))


lowest_grade = physics_students[0][1]

ind = 0
while physics_students[ind][1] == lowest_grade:
    ind += 1
    
second_lowest_grade = physics_students[ind][1]
second_lowest_students = []


while physics_students[ind][1] == second_lowest_grade:
    second_lowest_students.append(physics_students[ind][0])
    ind += 1
    if ind == num:
        break


second_lowest_students.sort()


print(*second_lowest_students, sep="\n")
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two occurrences of `studentrecord` refer to 2 different things

In the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), `studentrecord` is used to hold each element of the range `range(num)`. It's basically an index, but it's never used anyways.

Edit: I don't think the list comprehension should call it `studentrecord` because the elements of that range are indices and not lists representing a student's name and grade. It's a little confusing, and the variable should probably be renamed to something like `i` or `_`.

That list comprehension is like doing this:

```
physics_students = []
for studentrecord in range(num):
  physics_students.append([input("Input student name: "),float(input("Input grade: "))])
```

or this:

```
physics_students = []
for studentrecord in range(num):
  physics_students[studentrecord] = [input("Input student name: "),float(input("Input grade: "))]
```

In the [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), `studentrecord` is the name of the parameter to your anonymous function. It's like saying this:

```
def my_lambda(studentrecord):
  return float(studentrecord[1]
physics_students.sort(key=my_lambda)
```